# Combining multiple 2d arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following javascript code:

```
function Board() {
   // 2d array of 'Pieces'
  this.Map = [
    [new Piece(), new Piece(), new Piece()],
    [new Piece(), new Piece(), new Piece()],
    [new Piece(), new Piece(), new Piece()]
  ];

   // return full 9x9 2d integer array
   this.GetDetailedMap = function() {
     //?
   }
}

function Piece() {
   //2d array of integers
   this.Layout = [
     [1,0,1],
     [0,0,0],
     [1,0,1]
   ]
}

function DifferentPiece() {
   //2d array of integers
   this.Layout = [
     [1,0,1,1],
     [0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0],
     [1,0,1,1],
   ]
}
```

What `GetDetailedMap()` is supposed to do is return a 9x9 2d array consisting of the layout for every piece at the right index.

All 'Piece' layouts are always square. All pieces could be upscaled e.g.: 4x4, 6x6 etc. One piece 3x3 and another 4x4 should not be possible.

How would I implement the function?

EDIT:
I was close to solving it myself, but I had some errors, and my code wasn't as neat as the accepted answer.

Comment: How do you want them combined? There is a lot of ways 2d arrays could be combined. And what part of this problem has you stuck? How have you tried to combine them and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
this.GetDetailedMap = function flatMap() {
    var piecesize = this.Map[0][0].Layout.length;
    var detailedMap = [];
    for (var i=0; i<this.Map.length; i++) {
        var mapRow = this.Map[i];
        for (var j=0; j<piecesize; j++) {
            var detailedRow = [];
            for (var k=0; k<mapRow.length; k++) {
                var pieceRow = mapRow[k].Layout[j];
                for (var l=0; l<pieceRow.length; l++) {
                    detailedRow.push(pieceRow[l]);
                }
            }
            detailedMap.push(detailedRow);
        }
    }
    return detailedMap;
}
```

Comment: I was close to solving it myself, but your code is way cleaner! thanks alot! I had something along the same lines.